# TradingView pine script: Set percent of equity quantity for exiting position

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, trading, pine-script-v4

My position currently exits under the following condition:

```
sellCondition = (getSlope(MASIGNAL[0], MASIGNAL[1]) >= 0) and (cond1 == 1)
if (sellCondition and afterStartDate)
    strategy.entry("SELL", strategy.short)
```

How can I make this so only 25% of the position is exited? and in the event the condition is met again, it will continue selling of 25% until the position is 100% sold?

Comment: I think for exit from position you need to use `strategy.close` or `strategy.close_all`. There are qty_percent argument for partial position close in that functions.

Comment: Can I strategy.close conditionally? With an if statement?

Comment: yes of course .